# How can I see what's requiring NewtonSoft.Json 6.0.0.0 when everything in my solution references 8.0.3?

Tags: c#, json, dll, json.net, filenotfoundexception

My VS2015 solution (4.5.2) has 3 projects and 3 further test projects. 4 projects reference NewtonSoft.Json, all set to use version 8.0.3

All of the app.config and web.config files include redirects of

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
               publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

(and the configuration tag has no namespace attribute)

I run my tests on my dev box and all is sweet.

I deploy to our build server (TeamCity) which fails 47 of my tests saying

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Each compiled project has a copy of NewtonSoft.Json.Dll in its /bin/Release folder, and all are version 8.0.3

The build server has NewtonSoft.Json.Dll in its GAC at version 8.0.3

So here's what I need to know...

**How can I find out what's asking for version 6.0.0.0?**
and
**How do I kill it?**

Comment: FusionLog helped me see what's happening. Something (listed in the log as Assembly: (unknown)), asks for 6.0.0.0 and the dll's config file (sitting there in the /bin folder right next to the dll) is 'not found' so .Net goes direct to machine.config where there are no redirects so it fails the request. As a workaround I've added a redirect to machine.config so any request for 6 will be given 8 and all is well, but I'd still like to know who's asking for 6, and why the project config file is not seen..

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable [FusionLog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) to see which dll ask for this version of Newtonsoft.